# Finding assigned value in list

Tags: python-3.x

I am learning python i am having problem with list for example we have a list

```
list=[{'box':[1,2,3,4],'dog':67}]
```

in this list all value are assigned at one index only and at box attribute we assigned value.How we can find that what value are assigned in box attribute.

Answer (score 1):

`l[0]` is the dictionary with `dog` & `box`. You can access the entries in the dictionary with `d[key]` i.e.

```
>>> l=[{'box':[1,2,3,4],'dog':67}]
>>> l[0]  # this is the dict
{'box': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'dog': 67}
>>> l[0]['box'] # first get the dict, then a key in the dict
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```